# Check if list is in list of list

Tags: python

I have the following to check if list is in list of list.
It's returning wrong result. What's the issue in this?

```
my_list =  [['1', '2', '3'], ['7','8','9','10'], ['1','3','4','5'], ['10','11','12','13']]

w = ['1', '2', '3'] -> True

a = ['1','2'] -> True

b = ['7','8','9','10'] -> True

f = ['1', '0']  -> False

c = [['1','3','4','5'], ['10','11','12','13']]  -> True

d = [['1','3','4','4'], ['10','11','12','15']]  -> False

def x_in_y(search_list, my_list):
    return any([s in my_list for s in search_list])


print x_in_y(c, my_list)
print x_in_y(a, my_list)
```

partial match should be correct as well as long as all elements in list are present in my_list.

Comment: Your looping over elements of `search_list`, so presumably that should be a list of lists too? But you're only passing a simple list `w` as the argument

Comment: `... for s in search_list` means you're looping over the _individual elements_ of search_list, meaning in your example, you're looking for `'1'`, and that value by itself is not a member of your master list.

Comment: Do counts of the items matter? E.g., does the following test case pass or fail? `[['1','3','4','4'], ['10','11','12']]`. Also, does the order matter, and if so does relative order suffice?

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please don't vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they
  belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to
  you, it might still be  beneficial to someone in the future. If there
  is any confidential information revealed in your post, please edit it
  out with dummy data, and flag for the history to be redacted.

Answer (score 2):

you can directly check for containment of a list into a another list using `in`:

```
return search_list in my_list
```

but since you want also to get the partial containment match and even a list of a list containment, you can try this:

```
def x_in_y(search_list, my_list):
    if any(isinstance(i, list) for i in search_list):
        return all([x_in_y(x,my_list) for x in search_list])
    return any([m for m in my_list if m == search_list or set(search_list) <= set(m)])
```

this will check for list matches within list, a nested list containment, as well as subset of a list within list.

Comment: print x_in_y(a, my_list) and print x_in_y(c, my_list) show wrong result

Comment: why a must be True if the list value of a is not really on my_list?

Comment: I'm looking for partial match as well

Comment: it's returning true for partial match for list c, but failing for d. It's returning true even though 15 is in there.

Comment: @yomangz1 please check my edits. that function will check even nested list

Comment: I generally like this answer, but it's one of the only ones that can't handle lists that mutually contain each other without erroring due to infinite recursion. Set up the test case with `a=[]; b=[a]; a.append(b)`, or if you're fine with the test objects being the same you can get the same error with `a=[]; a.append(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `in` keyword to check if your list is present:

```
def x_in_y(search_list, my_list):
    return True if search_list in my_list else False
```

Comment: print x_in_y(w, my_list) is returning false when it should be true

Comment: That's desired outcome

Answer (score 1):

You  need to handle the one dimensional case separately

```
def x_in_y(search_list, my_list):
    return (search_list in my_list) or any([s in my_list for s in search_list])
```

Answer (score 1):

This code although more lines than the list comprehension, in some cases it will be faster because it breaks once any item is not found.

```
def x_in_y(search_list, my_list):
    for num in search_list:
        for lst in my_list:
            found=False
            if num in lst or num==lst:
                found=True
                break
        if found==False:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```
search_list = [['1', '2', '3'], ['7','8','9','10'], 
               ['1','3','4','5'], ['10','11','12','13']]

w = ['1', '2', '3']  # True
a = ['1', '2']  # True
b = ['7', '8', '9', '10']  # True
f = ['1', '0']  # False
c = [['1', '3', '4', '5'], ['10', '11', '12', '13']]  # True
d = [['1', '3', '4', '4'], ['10', '11', '12', '15']]  # False
```

Function:
 - using generator comprehension instead of list comprehension
 - code below needs hashable inputs

```
def x_in_y(x, y):
    # check if x is a nested list
    if any(isinstance(i, list) for i in x):
        return x, all((any((set(x_).issubset(y_) for y_ in y)) for x_ in x))
    else:
        return x, any((set(x).issubset(y_) for y_ in y))
```

> [all()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) : Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty)
>   [any()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) : Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False
>   [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) : Return true if the each item in x is an instance of the list
>   [issubset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=issubset) : Test whether every element in the set is in argument set

Result:

```
print(x_in_y(w, search_list))
## (['1', '2', '3'], True)
print(x_in_y(a, search_list))
## (['1', '2'], True)
print(x_in_y(b, search_list))
## (['7', '8', '9', '10'], True)
print(x_in_y(f, search_list))
## (['1', '0'], False)
print(x_in_y(c, search_list))
## ([['1', '3', '4', '5'], ['10', '11', '12', '13']], True)
print(x_in_y(d, search_list))
## ([['1', '3', '4', '4'], ['10', '11', '12', '15']], False)
```

Comment: The same test cases that break @mark's code apply here (though for different reasons). Run `a=[];a.append(a);x_in_y(a,a)` to get an unhashable type error.

Comment: @Hans the OP indicated Mark's code fails for "d" nested list by returning true.  the code above correctly return's false.  it meets all test cases provided by the OP.  I am sure one could find few other cases that will break the code but I don't think that is the intent here.

Comment: Perhaps, but with SO's stated goal of providing a repository of knowledge and a policy of actively avoiding questions and answers that are too tailored to a single individual or scenario it would be nice to at least acknowledge potential problems that could arise when somebody goes to adapt your code (e.g., not being able to replace strings with an unhashable type -- even builtin types like lists). I rather like your code, but the answer should mention reasonable edge cases.

Comment: As a bit of a fun tidbit, you'll get way better memory usage and also typically better CPU usage by using generator comprehensions rather than list comprehensions, e.g. with `all(any(set(x_).issubset(y_) for y_ in y) for x_ in x)`

Comment: @HansMusgrave good catch on generators - changed code accordingly.  also added a caveat for non-hashable inputs.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
def x_in_y(search_list, my_list):
    return (search_list in my_list)
```